# Create expression tree for "like" on a decimal field

Tags: c#, lambda, llblgenpro, llblgen

I would like to create an expression tree for a query expression that looks something like this:
   employee => employee.Salary.StartsWith("28")

So that the sql could appear as:
   where (employee.salary like '28%')

The problem is that the property Salary of the employee object is a decimal and StartsWith is not a property of a decimal. How can i get around to do this.

My erroneous expression tree syntax is as follows:

```
var searchTextExp = Expression.Constant("28");
var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EmployeeEntity), "employee");
var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "Salary");
var startsWithExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, "StartsWith", null, 
   searchTextExp);
Expression<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>> searchExpr = 
   Expression.Lambda<Func<EmployeeEntity, bool>>
     (startsWithExp, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExp });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this using Function Mappings which is a feature of LLBLGEN Pro.

```
public class Functions
{
    public static bool Like(string field, string value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool Like(decimal field, string value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class FunctionMappings : FunctionMappingStore
{
    public FunctionMappings()
        : base()
    {
        FunctionMapping mapping = new FunctionMapping(
            typeof(Functions), 
            "Like", 
            2, 
            "{0} LIKE {1}");

        this.Add(mapping);
    }
}
```

I then attached an instance of FunctionMappings to the LINQ Metadata:

```
metadata.Mappings = new FunctionMappings();
```

Then used the Function as follows:

```
employee => Functions.Like(employee.Salary,"28")
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the easiest solution (that will probably also work in Linq to Sql) is:

```
employee => employee.Salary.ToString().StartsWith("28");
```

Comment: Hmmm. I am using linq to llblgen and an error is thrown since "ToString" does not have a conversion equivalent when being parsed. I have tried that and: employee => Convert.ToString(employee.Salary).StartsWith("28"); which also does not work.

Comment: So that's maybe more a problem of llblgen ... But the Linq Expression is correct that way.

Comment: I also think thats the problem. I have logged the query in the llblgen forum.

Answer (score 0):

If llblgen does not support ToString() you can workaround the problem by creating a View that does the cast. What's your target database?

If it's SQL Server you can use the CAST() function to create the view.

e.g.

```
  CREATE VIEW viewName as 
    SELECT CAST(Salary as varchar) as Salary
    FROM Employee
```

After that you should be able to map that view against a new class and do the query like stated above.

```
employee = employee.Salary.StartsWith("28");
```

Comment: It does support tostring(), but in the db that's a convert to char, which doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The view would be a nice idea but I dont have a say in how the db is designed. Views are used to implement security and thats just about it. The database is oracle 10g. @Bouma. When I use ToString(), I get a runtime error that object doesnt have a property ToString(). Which doesnt make sense because it has.

Comment: Although it's not up to you to decide, I would suggest using a "View" to solve the problem. Otherwise you'll have to amend the ORM you are using - which would cause much more effort to you ...